# How to store hateoas structure in elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-hateoas, hateoas

I have the following problem that I need to save a Hateos structure in Elasticsearch using the save method in the Springboot application, but I get the error message "stackoverflowerror null": Could some body please check my code to see where I am making mistakes ? It really took me a long time to demonstrate this example.

> Config.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.demo.elsticsearch")
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient client() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration
                = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

> UserResourceAssembler.java

```
@Service
public class UserResourseAssembler extends RepresentationModelAssemblerSupport<User, UserResourse> {

    public UserResourseAssembler() {
        super(JsController.class, UserResourse.class);
    }

    @Override
    public UserResourse toModel(User user) {
        UserResourse resource = UserResourse.builder().email("jjj").firstName("hii").lastName("hoo").loginId("123").build();

        resource.add(linkTo(methodOn(JsController.class).getByLoginId(user.getLoginId())).withRel("self"));
        return resource;
    }
}
```

> Repo.java

```
@Repository
public interface Repo extends ElasticsearchRepository<UserResourse, String> {
    List<UserResourse> findByLoginId(String loginId);
}
```

> User.java

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private String loginId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
}
```

> UserResourse.java

```
@Mapping(mappingPath = "/files.json")
@Document(indexName = "files", type = "file")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserResourse extends RepresentationModel<UserResourse> {
    @Id
    private String loginId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
}
```

> JsController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class JsController {
    private final Repo repository;
    private final UserResourseAssembler userResourseAssembler;

    @GetMapping("/check")
    public ResponseEntity<UserResourse> uploadData() {
        User user = new User(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "hi", "hello", "jj");
        UserResourse userResourse = userResourseAssembler.toModel(user);
        repository.save(userResourse);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userResourse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/jobId")
    public List<UserResourse> getByLoginId(@PathVariable String loginId) {
        return repository.findByLoginId(loginId);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
2020-09-18 10:02:35.939 ERROR 16184 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Cannot render document to JSON] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: I have the same error

Comment: Why do you want to put the RepresentationModel (UserResourse) in ElasticSearch? It adds a lot of extra fields that are just for hateoas. Why not just save the User, and convert it to the UserResourse when you read it?

Comment: Can you please explain your idea based on  changing my code please? maybe this can help me